# How can I focus on a given table's row using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a big html table with many rows that does not fit on the screen, do you know how to focus on a given row with javascript/jquery avoiding the need to scroll down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the "scrollIntoView" function. It's supported on most elements by (I think) all the browsers.

What I do, when I want to make a table (or something like a table) behave that way, I make sure that the target table row has a special class, or maybe an "id" value. Then I can find the row with Javascript and call "scrollIntoView()".  The only thing you have to watch out for is that sometimes IE gets confused and screws up layout around the table, but if you're careful with how you set up scrollable elements it usually can be made to work.

Comment: Thanks, i have resolved with:
$('tr')[given_row].scrollIntoView();