# focus <tr> element in scrollable <div>

Tags: jquery, scroll

```
        var newrow =
     $(
     "<tr id=" + mahs + ">"
    + "<td id=\"stt\">" + $("#txtIncrement").val() + "</td>"
    + "<td id=\"mahs\">" + mahs + "</td>"
    + "<td id=\"fullname\">" + $("#txtFullname").val() + "</td>"
    + "<td id=\"delete\">" + "<a href=\"#\"><img src=\"/Contents/Images/delete.png\" style=\"width:30px;height:30px;\" alt=\"\" /></a>" + "</td>"
    + "</tr>");
    $("#tbContent").append(newrow);
```

I use this code to add a new row to table(tbContent) in div tags below.

```
 <div  id="scrollpanel" class="cvleft" style="height:417px; overflow:scroll;">
        <table id="tbContent">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>STT</th>
                <th>HS</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Delete</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

How can I focus that row when it added to table ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to scroll to the bottom of the div after you enter a new row, try something like this:

```
var height = $('#scrollpanel')[0].scrollHeight;
$('#scrollpanel').scrollTop(height);
```

Or if you'd like to have it animated:

```
var height = $('#scrollpanel')[0].scrollHeight;
$("#scrollpanel").animate({ scrollTop: height}, 1000);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Glad we could help.  If any of the answers were useful, please accept.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How bout trying -- using jquery when the row is added maybe like -->

```
$('#scrollpanel').scrollIntoView()
```

[How can I focus on a given table's row using javascript/jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188245/how-can-i-focus-on-a-given-tables-row-using-javascript-jquery)